# Excel email reminder to outlook when excel gets updated

Tags: vba, excel

Ok , so, anyone know if it is possible to send an email reminder from excel to outlook automatically every time the excel sheet gets updated? If so, how that part of the macro would look like? I cant find it online anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

The following code seems to work.
  Right click on a worksheet and select 'View code'
  and select Change event for Worksheet.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim OutApp As Object
Dim OutMail As Object
Dim strbody As String

Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

strbody = "Hi there" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
          "This is line 1" & vbNewLine & _
          "This is line 2" & vbNewLine & _
          "This is line 3" & vbNewLine & _
          "This is line 4"

On Error Resume Next
With OutMail
    .To = "someone@someemail.com"
    .CC = ""
    .BCC = ""
    .Subject = "This is the Subject line"
    .Body = strbody
    'You can add a file like this
    '.Attachments.Add ("C:\test.txt")
    .Send   'or use .Display
End With
On Error GoTo 0

Set OutMail = Nothing
Set OutApp = Nothing
End Sub
```